# document.getElementById(name).options[0] work in IE but doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use the tree in project but it is working in IE but isn't working in Chrome. I saw this code `document.getElementById(name).options[0]` it doesnt work in Chrome and Firefox. How can i pass the this problem or alternative this code ?
My js code

```
function bosalt(elm)
{
    alert("bosalt function");
    while(document.getElementById(elm).options[0]!=null)
        document.getElementById(elm).options[0]=null;
}
```

and another place;

```
function listele(elm,val,txt)
{
    alert("fasa fiso");
    document.getElementById(elm).options[document.getElementById(elm).length]=new Option(txt,val);
}
```

I saw it isnt working because when i add block comment this code the project is running.
Please help me. And thank you so much everything.

Comment: Did you use any plugins..

Comment: please create a jsFiddle with a narrowed down code reproducing the error...

Comment: wich type of field is `name` ?? it have some elements inside?? for me `document.getElementById("nameOfTheField").options[0]` in a dropbox is working perfect...

Comment: elm='program' yes it has elements and it is combobox. It is working in IE but not Chrome. Do you test in Chrome @JordiCastilla?

Comment: No sankar ı dont use. Bartdude i am new js and do you help me how can i create jsFiddle?

Comment: yes, It is working in `Chrome` and `Firefox` for me... it happens the same if you hardcode it: `document.getElementById("program").options[0]` ??

Comment: i try but it doesnt happen anything :( and i use alert : alert(document.getElementById("program").options[0])  but isnt coming any message alert.

Comment: @JordiCastilla i use this in popup i forgat to say this. Is it important?

Comment: maybe... can you post the important code of the html???

Comment: Important code ? for function of course and i use alert and they are  coming

Comment: i tested code in tesy.html it is working <html>
<body>
<script>
    function myNewFunction(sel)
    {
   alert(sel.options[0].text);
        alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>

<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
    <option value="98">dog</option>
    <option value="7122">cat</option>
    <option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>

Comment: but in big project it doesnt work?